# Move first 5 files out of 100 from one directory to another using Python code

Tags: python, azure-databricks

Is it possible to move the first 5 files from one directory to another using python code?
I have to run the code on the data bricks notebook.

The scenario is: I have to pick any first 5 files present in the directory (total files is 100) and move those 5 files to another directory, this process will be repeated till all the files moved to another folder.

Comment: what do you mean by "top 5" ?

Comment: Pick any first 5 files present in the directory (total files is 100) and move those 5 files to another directory, this process will be repeated till all the files moved to the another folder.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Its a azure databricks notebook running on Linux kernel. I have achieved the result via Linux command "%sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f |head -2|xargs mv -t "/dbfs/mnt/dev/Devices/temp/xml/" " but the problem on data bricks is , I can't run linux command and python command in one cell.

Answer (score 2):

*r''* - rawstring literal (to ignore backslashes in the string)

```
import os
import shutil

source = r'C:\Python38-32'                # files location
destination = r'C:\New Folder'            # where to move to 
folder = os.listdir(source)               # returns a list with all the files in source

while folder:                             # True if there are any files, False if empty list
   for i in range(5):                     # 5 files at a time 
      file = folder[0]                    # select the first file's name
      curr_file = source + '\\' + file    # creates a string - full path to the file
      shutil.move(curr_file, destination) # move the files
      folder.pop(0)                       # Remove the moved file from the list
```

Worked for me, moves the files from one directory (`source`) to another (`destination`)